# Accessing App.config in a location different from the binary

Tags: c#

In a .NET Win console application, I would like to access an App.config file in a location different from the console application binary. For example, how can C:\bin\Text.exe get its settings from C:\Test.exe.config?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
using System.Configuration;    

Configuration config =
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("C:\Test.exe");
```

You can then access the app settings, connection strings, etc from the config instance.  This assumes of course that the config file is properly formatted and your app has read access to the directory.  Notice the path is ***not*** "C:\Test.exe.config"  The method looks for a config file associated with the file you specify.  If you specify "C:\Test.exe.config" it will look for "C:\Test.exe.config.config"  Kinda lame, but understandable, I guess.

Reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openexeconfiguration.aspx

Comment: One gotcha with this method is that the file "C:\Test.exe" must exist, even if it's not a valid executable.

Comment: What about any thing else that assumes you have your connection string in your app.config is your bin ?
like EntityFramework which automatically retrieves your connection string from you app.config .
The question here is how can i tell the configuration manager look for my config in a location. not create an instance from some location and pass it around

Answer (score 8):

It appears that you can use the [`AppDomain.SetData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37z40s1c.aspx) method to achieve this. The documentation states:

> You cannot insert or modify system entries with this method.

Regardless, doing so does appear to work. The documentation for the [`AppDomain.GetData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getdata.aspx) method lists the system entries available, of interest is the `"APP_CONFIG_FILE"` entry.

If we set the `"APP_CONFIG_FILE"` before any application settings are used, we can modify where the `app.config` is loaded from. For example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", @"C:\Temp\test.config");
        //...
    }
}
```

I found this solution documented in [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/01/10/349825.aspx) and a more complete answer (to a related question) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6151688/142794).

Answer (score 6):

Use the following (remember to include System.Configuration assembly)

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set it by creating a new app domain:

```
AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
domainSetup.ConfigurationFile = fileLocation;
AppDomain add = AppDomain.CreateDomain("myNewAppDomain", securityInfo, domainSetup);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
        domainSetup.ConfigurationFile = @"D:\Mine\Company\";
        string browserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["browser"];
```