# Launch process not from application path

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console app that I have to launch from my code. This app has a configuration file that locates in the same folder. If I launch console app manually it finds the configuration file and everything goes fine. But when I launch it as a process in my code it tries to find configuration in my app's folder, so I need to copy it to Debug/Release folder. Can I avoid this behavior because I want this console app to locate independently as a module?

Comment: So you have DirectoryA => {DDL_A, Config_A} and  DirectoryB => {DDL_B, Config_B}. And A is calling B. B need for example a connnexion string that is only in Config_B. Or is A trying to get Config_B.

Comment: Related : [Accessing App.config in a location different from the binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75978/)

Comment: Thank's for your replies, InBetween gave me a question. Config file was not an "App.config", it was a file that just read from console app and parsing manually.

Comment: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` will give you the current location of the dll executing this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the `WorkingDirectory` of your process. Check [`ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=netcore-3.1) for more information.

In your case you probably want to set `UseShellExecute` to `false` and set the working directory to the executable's location.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to load the file from the executing assembly.
`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` will give you the current location of the ddl executing this code.

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```